# My WPF application is not updating the xaml textblock text while using INotifyPropertyChanged interface

Tags: c#, json, wpf, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class that has a few properties (AlertMsg.cs) and it's using the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Using xaml I included the namespace for that class to my window (MainWindow.xaml). Intellisense helped me add a datacontext and bind those properties to my window element using just xaml. So I know my window is aware of the properties. When I run the application in visual studio the textblock loads my constructor values from the class. So I'm feeling pretty good about it being bound to the property.

I have another class (PubNubAlerts.cs) that listens for an incoming json, it parses the json and sets those values to my property class (AlertMsg.cs). This part also works just fine because I can see the properties changing in my output window. When the properties change it even steps through the PropertyChanged method, but when I go to look at the UI for my window (MainWindow) the constructor values loaded at initialization are still present. I want them to update with the incoming json data. What am I missing as far implementing INotifyPropertyChanged ?

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:Models="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Models" 
        x:Name="AlertPopup" x:Class="MyApplication.MainWindow" 
        Title="AlertMsg" Height="350" Width="525" WindowState="Normal">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <Models:AlertMsg />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid Background="White" Opacity="0.8">
        <TabItem Width="500" Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            <Frame Source="MainPage.xaml" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="500" Height="297" FontSize="20" />
        </TabItem>
        <Border Background="{Binding Path=PopUpBackGroundColor, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="4" Opacity="0.8" Width="300" Height="80">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Path=MainMessage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;


namespace MyApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ThreeDBorderWindow;
            Height = 400;
            Width = 400;

        }
    }
}
```

AlertMsg.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System;

namespace MyApplication.Models
{
    // interface
    class AlertMsg : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        //// constructor, some default values
        public AlertMsg()
        {
            this.MainMessage = "TEXT GOES HERE";
            this.PopUpBackGroundColor = "Red";
        }


        // main message property
        private string mainMessage;
        public string MainMessage
        {
            get
            {
                return this.mainMessage;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.mainMessage)
                {
                    this.mainMessage = value;

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MainMessage is now = " + value);

                    OnPropertyChanged("MainMessage");

                }
            }
        }
        //background color property of message
        private string popupBackGroundColor;
        public string PopUpBackGroundColor
        {
            get
            {
                return this.popupBackGroundColor;
            }
            set
            {

                if (value != this.popupBackGroundColor)
                {
                    this.popupBackGroundColor = value;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("popupbackgroundcolor is now = " + value);
                    OnPropertyChanged("PopUpBackGroundColor");
                }
            }
        }


        // call this method on the setter of every property
        // should change the text of the view
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            try
            {
                // change property
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {

                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Property " + propertyName + " changed.");

                }
            }
            catch (InvalidAsynchronousStateException e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Invalid Asynchrounous State Exception" + e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception generalException)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error OnPropertyChanged: " + propertyName + " " + generalException.Message);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

PubNubAlerts.cs   (third party that feeds me the json. you can be less concerned with this as I know its updating my properties but i included it anyways just in case.)

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using PubnubApi;
using MyApplication.Models;


namespace MyApplication
{
    public class PubNubAlerts
    {
        static public Pubnub pubnub;
// hardcoded values for testing
        static public string channel = "TestChannel";
        static public string authKey = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        static public string subscribeKey = "xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx";
        static public string channelGroup = "";
        static public string mainBody;

        AlertMsg alertMsg = new AlertMsg();

        public void PubNubSubscribe()
        {
            // config 
            PNConfiguration config = new PNConfiguration()
            {
                AuthKey = authKey,
                Secure = false,
                SubscribeKey = subscribeKey,
                LogVerbosity = PNLogVerbosity.BODY
            };
            try
            {

                pubnub = new Pubnub(config);

                // add listener 
                pubnub.AddListener(new SubscribeCallbackExt(
                 (pubnubObj, message) => {
         // grab data from json and parse
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pubnub.JsonPluggableLibrary.SerializeToJsonString(message));
                     string jsonMessage = pubnub.JsonPluggableLibrary.SerializeToJsonString(message);
                     dynamic data = JObject.Parse(jsonMessage);
         // update alertmsg properties with json from pubnub
         alertMsg.MainMessage = data.Message.mainmessage;
                     alertMsg.PopUpBackGroundColor = data.Message.popupbackgroundcolor;


                 },
                 (pubnubObj, presence) => {
                     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pubnub.JsonPluggableLibrary.SerializeToJsonString(presence));
                 },
                 (pubnubObj, status) => {
                     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} ", status.Operation, status.Category, status.StatusCode);
                 }
                ));

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Running subscribe()");

                // subscribe
                pubnub.Subscribe<object>()
                 .WithPresence()
                 .Channels(channel.Split(','))
                 .ChannelGroups(channelGroup.Split(','))
                 .Execute();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("FAILED TO SUBSCRIBE: " + e.Message);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

[MainWindow Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE0T4.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two different instances of `AlertMsg`.

In 'MainWindow.xaml' you are instantiating an instance as your window's data context here:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <Models:AlertMsg />
</Window.DataContext>
```

And in 'PubNubAlerts.cs' you are instantiating an instance around line 19:

```
AlertMsg alertMsg = new AlertMsg();
```

You need to pass your window's `DataContext` to `PubNubAlerts` or you need to expose the instance that `PubNubAlerts` uses and bind your window's `DataContext` to it.

Comment: So yes, having two different instances of anything would not work. I created a property inside pubnub, made it public and switched the datacontext to the pubnub property and it started updating my MainWindow. Thank you very much.